# Что такое криптоядро?

Tags: криптография, терминология

Не могу найти, что такое "криптоядро"?

Comment: 3 года криптографией занимаюсь - первый раз слышу. Так что какая-то неведомая фигня это.

Comment: у меня есть два варианта - либо это самая центральная часть алгоритма криптования, либо это часть какой-то программы, которая отвечает за криптографию.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&espv=2&biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=isch&imgil=xaxja3eEvAtsSM%253A%253BtPjv09vi00RSjM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.okbsapr.ru%25252Fborisova_2012_3.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=xaxja3eEvAtsSM%253A%252CtPjv09vi00RSjM%252C_&usg=__E-VNoRC27lmLjKbc56pJDDBWWOM%3D&ved=0ahUKEwi1rYzV6MXOAhVFjiwKHYPxAAAQyjcIQw&ei=FPeyV7XTGMWcsgGD4wM#imgrc=xaxja3eEvAtsSM%3A

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я давно уже этим не занимаюсь, поэтому не был уверен что не напутал чего-нибудь.

Comment: Блин, а за что минус ?

Comment: Какой-то мегамозг придумал термин, ничего особенного.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Некий "черный ящик", на вход которого подаются исходные данные (и ключ), а на выходе получаются зашифрованные данные (и наоборот). Используется, насколько я знаю, для сертификации криптосистем, чтобы не сертифицировать весь программный комплекс - можно купить готовое, сертифицированное КЯ и использовать его для шифрования данных.